# Using value from http get inside PipeTransform in angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am creating an APP that has a `PipeTransform` that gets a specific character set typed by the customer and transforms it into a link.

New character set needs to do an `HTTP get` to get `Id` and `Name` of the user, so I can get these data but when trying to create a link `outside _HttpService.get` return `Undefined` value.

How can I use these values, `userId`, and `userName`, `outside _HttpService.get`?

Updated the post, when I have to search data from DB return undefined.

```
transform(value: any): SafeHtml {
    
    // Return undefined
    if (this._PatternService._Pattern__tagVisitG.test(value)) {
        this.email = value.match(this._PatternService._Pattern__tagVisit)[2];

        this._HttpService.get(`${ServerUrl.ApiUrl}tag/email/${this.email}`)
            .pipe(map(data => {
                this.result = data;
                this.userId = this.result.response[0]._id;
                this.userName = this.result.response[0].name;
                this.newValue = value.replace(this._PatternService._Pattern__tagVisit, `<a href="#" id="visitLink" data-id=${this.userId}/>${this.userName}</a>`);
            })
            );

        // return undefind
        console.log(this.newValue);
    }

    // Pipe create link to copy post number, it is working
    else if (this._PatternService._Pattern__tagCorreiosG.test(value)) {
        this.correios = value.match(this._PatternService._Pattern__tagCorreios)[2];
        this.correiosLink = `<a href="#" id="correiosLink" data-correios=${this.correios}>${this.correios}</a>`;
        this.newValue = value.replace(this._PatternService._Pattern__tagCorreios, this.correiosLink);
    }

    // Return value when there is no tag, it is working
    else {
        this.newValue = value;
    }

    return this._DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.newValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How can I use these values, userId, and userName, outside _HttpService.get **within
the same function**?

Answer: you can't. You have to chain logic **at the observable** if you want to use **its returned values**. The code outside of the observable gets executed first. Then (whenever the observable resolves) the code chained at the observable gets executed (as long as you subscribe somewhere):

UserId and UserName get set after you arrive at this passage of your code:

```
 **=> Using console.log here return Undefined**
    console.log(this.userId);
```

This is why `this.userId` is still undefined when you log it. The only reasonable way to operate here is to return an observable:

```
   transform(value: any): Observable<SafeHtml> {
    if (this._PatternService._Pattern__tagVisitG.test(value)) {
      this.email = value.match(this._PatternService._Pattern__tagVisit)[2];

      return this._HttpService
        .get(`${ServerUrl.ApiUrl}tag/email/${this.email}`)
        .pipe(
          map(data => {
            this.result = data;
            this.userId = this.result.response[0]._id;
            this.userName = this.result.response[0].name;
            this.newValue = value.replace(
              this._PatternService._Pattern__tagVisit,
              `<a href="#" id="visitLink" data-id=${this.userId}/>${
                this.userName
              }</a>`
            );
            return this._DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.newValue);
          })
        );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi BLD.. thanks for your comment.. Not workd your example.. I updated the post.